# Non-algebraic representations of $\text{SL}_n(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: rt.representation-theory, lie-groups, algebraic-groups

My question is easily stated: are all continuous finite-dimensional real representations of $\text{SL}_n(\mathbb{R})$ algebraic representations?

This is false if you drop the word "continuous" (e.g. using noncontinuous field automorphisms of $\mathbb{R}$).

It is also false if you work with $\text{GL}_n(\mathbb{R})$ instead of $\text{SL}_n(\mathbb{R})$.  For instance, there are many examples in the answers to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/694001/non-polynomial-representations-of-gl-n) question.  However, all of the continuous examples there use the determinant in some way, so they don't give examples of non-algebraic representations of $\text{SL}_n(\mathbb{R})$.

Comment: Doesn't it follow from Margulis' rigidity results?

Comment: @MarkSapir: Margulis's super-rigidity implies that every representation of SL(n,Z) virtually extends to a continuous representation of SL(n,R), but as far as I know (I am not an expert) it just gives a continuous extension.  I would also expect that if this is true, then invoking Margulis would be like killing a fly with a nuclear bomb.

Comment: Every field automorphism of $\mathbf{R}$ is continuous (however you get representation using non-continuous field embeddings into $\mathbf{C}$).

Comment: The answer to your question is yes, and more generally true for every connected semisimple Lie group, and even perfect is enough. This is due to the fact that every perfect subalgebra of matrices is the Lie algebra of an algebraic subgroup. This can be applied to the (Lie algebra of the) graph of your representation.

Comment: @YCor: Maybe one should mention that this graph is a closed subgroup of a Lie group, hence a Lie subgroup, and therefore algebraic by your argument.

Comment: @YCor: "Every field automorphism of R is continuous": Even more is true: The identity is the only field automorphism of $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @YCor, the implication "perfect matrix Lie algebra $\implies$ Lie algebra of algebraic group" doesn't seem to be easily googlable. Could convert your comment into a short answer with a reference?

Comment: I found a reference for the result YCor quoted: it is Corollary 7.9 in Borel's book "Linear Algebraic Groups".

Comment: @YCor: Thanks for the comment.  Your answer is convincing; however, I am puzzled by one thing.  In the paper "Rationality of representations of linear Lie groups" by D. H. Lee and T. S. Wu (Proc. Amer. Math. Soc. 114 (1992), no. 3, 847-855), the authors claim that there are counterexamples to this among connected semisimple real algebraic groups.  Their paper uses too much Lie theory for me to easily follow it.  How can I reconcile what they do with what you do?

Comment: (this paper is what originally led me to worry that there might be counterexamples for $\text{SL}_n(\mathbb{R})$)

Comment: Thanks for the reference! Indeed my argument was too sloppy. One more problem with dealing with algebraic geometry while working with real points! Indeed the idea is to say that the graph of the representation is an algebraic subgroup... But at the level of complex points it's no longer the graph of a map in their example. Nevertheless, this seems to still hold for simply connected $G$ (in the algebraic sense), and in particular for $\mathrm{SL}_n(\mathbf{R})$. Indeed Theorem 1 (equivalence between (iii) and (iv)) of your linked paper answers your question.

Comment: PS: link to the Proc AMS paper: https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1992-114-03/S0002-9939-1992-1072344-X/S0002-9939-1992-1072344-X.pdf

Comment: To summarize the counterexample: consider the homomorphism $\mathrm{SL}_3\to\mathrm{PGL}_3$, whose kernel has order 3. At the level of real points, it induces a homomorphism $f$ between unit components. Then $f^{-1}$ is an isomorphism of the underlying Lie groups that is not algebraic.

Comment: @YCor: Thanks!  Can you say a bit more about why (iv) in the linked paper has something to do with the algebraic group being simply-connected?  It seems to be a rather different condition (but as I work in a different area, I might be missing some equivalences that are obvious to specialists).

Comment: I didn't mean this (although it should be true): I'm just saying that $G=\mathrm{SL}_n(\mathbf{R})$ satisfies (iv) (namely that the inclusion of $G$ in its (complex) Zariski closure is its complexification).

Comment: @YCor: Got it, thanks!